# Symfony won't show the form submission errors when the template changed

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

Would anyone know the solution for the issue below?

Note: Symfony footer information bar (profiler) has the errors so system catches them. Template below belogs to FOSUserBundle.

**When I use this (original) edit page, I can see the form validation errors in the page:**

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_profile_edit">
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="{{ 'profile.edit.submit'|trans }}" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

**When I use this (modified) one, I cannot see the form validation errors in the page:**

```
    <form action="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_profile_edit">
    <div>{{ form_errors(form) }}</div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.username) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.email) }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Current Password</td>
            <td>{{ form_widget(form.current_password) }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'profile.edit.submit'|trans }}" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting `error_bubbling` in your form. According to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling):

`If true, any errors for this field will be passed to the parent field or form. For example, if set to true on a normal field, any errors for that field will be attached to the main form, not to the specific field.`

so if `error_bubbling` is set to false (by default) you should display error messages for specific fields like:

```
<tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.username) }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_errors(form.username) }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'll check it on monday and I believe that will solve the problem cos I used it before but for some reason brain run out of juice time to time!